# Sharepoint refine results control only uses the current pages values

Tags: sharepoint, search

I have a [SharePoint refine search results control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.refinesearchresults_members.aspx) on my people search results page.
Paging is on for the search results.
The control only refines the current pages results.

How do I change this behaviour so that despite the core results being paged, the refine results works on all results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it can't be done.  Sorting and refining only work on the results returned for the page, as defined in the Search Core Results Web Part XSLT.  It's a real shame, too.  But if you never get back more than 50 hits and you have max items set to 50, you'll get what you want.  :-)